# How to escape all strings in a bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash, escaping

I have some bash array `arr_a`, I want to obtain an array `arr_b` whose elements are the result of escaping the corresponding elements of `arr_a`.

Thus if

```
arr_a=("foo\"" "bar")
```

then `arr_a[0]` contains `foo"` and `arr_a[1]` contains `bar`; and I want `arr_b[0]` to contain `foo\"` and `arr_b[1]` to contain `bar`.

I know I can escape a single string with `printf %q "$the_string"`. The problem is, if I do this in a function or a subshell or what-not, I "lose" the escaping by printing the escaped string to the output stream of the function. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: `I "lose" the escaping by printing the escaped string to the output stream of the function` What do you mean by that? How do you lose that?

Answer (score 6):

> then arr_a[0] contains foo" and arr_a[1] contains bar; and I want arr_b[0] to contain foo" and arr_b[1] to contain bar.
> What's the right way to do this?

Print the escaped array elements as a stream of zero separated elements and then load that stream into an array.

```
arr_a=("foo\"" "bar")
readarray -t -d '' arr_b < <(printf "%q\0" "${arr_a[@]}")
echo arr_b[0]="${arr_b[0]}"
echo arr_b[1]="${arr_b[1]}"
```

would output:

```
arr_b[0]=foo\"
arr_b[1]=bar
```